# Replace an existing XML file using Webservice in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, web-applications, flex4, weborb

Is it possible to Replace an existing XML file using Webservice in Flex(browser-based application)?

I wanted to replace an existing xml file with new xml file of same name for example 'dashboard.xml'.

How can i replace this file from Flex browser-based application? can this is possible using webservice?

what things should be taken care to implement this?

my application is based on flex and .NET.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible and common to do.  Can you show us your existing code so we can show you how to change it?

Comment: I havn't started coding part yet. I am finding the alternatives to achieve this thing. Is there any better way to get it done from flex-browser based application?

Comment: I presume you are going to have to use some server-side script. I dont think Flex can write an xml file directly. Can someone confirm this presumption?

Comment: @Brian Bishop Correct; the Flash Player cannot write files to a server. It can write files to the local machine, but not w/o user input.

Comment: Gotcha.  I thought you meant that you had code that was reading an XML file and you wanted to change it to get the data from a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Very possible and in most cases, very easy with Flex.

In fact, depending on how you're loading it, it could easily be as simple as changing the  myFile.xml to  http://domain.com/myFile.aspx on the service your using.

If you post some code, we'll point you in the right direction.